# Null Pointer Exception with Jsoup Parse

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsoup

So I have sifted thought some code and cannot trouble shoot this null pointer exception error.

I'm trying to parse a tables from source code lines 2290 to 3153 http://pastebin.com/DjGHED5t

However, in one of my CSS queries the code fails and makes no sense to me why.

```
public void updateCompanyIs()throws IOException{
    investoolsLogin();

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://toolbox.investools.com/graphs/fundamentalAnalysis.iedu?report=BS&symbol="+(Ticker)).get();
    // Elements table = doc.select("table");
/**LINE 72**/ 
    Elements columns = doc.getElementById("fundamentalsForm").children().select("table").get(0).select("tr").get(0).select("td");
    Iterator<Element> columnIterator = columns.iterator();
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
        while (columnIterator.hasNext()) {
            Element column = columnIterator.next();
            Elements rows = column.select("table").get(0).select("tr");
            Iterator<Element> rowsIterator = rows.iterator();
            col = col + 1;
            while (rowsIterator.hasNext()){
                row = row + 1;
                //Element rowIterator.next = ;
                incomeStatementInfo[col][row] = rowsIterator.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateCompanyBs()throws IOException{
        investoolsLogin();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://toolbox.investools.com/graphs/fundamentalAnalysis.iedu?report=BS&symbol="+(Ticker)).get();
        // Elements table = doc.select("table");
        Elements columns = doc.getElementById("fundamentalsForm").children().select("table").get(0).select("tr").get(0).select("td");
        Iterator<Element> columnIterator = columns.iterator();
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        while (columnIterator.hasNext()) {
            Element column = columnIterator.next();
            Elements rows = column.select("table").get(0).select("tr");
            Iterator<Element> rowsIterator = rows.iterator();
            col = col + 1;
            while (rowsIterator.hasNext()){
                row = row + 1;
                //Element rowIterator.next = ;
                balanceSheetInfo[col][row] = rowsIterator.next();
            }
        }
    }   

    public void updateCompanyCf()throws IOException{
        investoolsLogin();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://toolbox.investools.com/graphs/fundamentalAnalysis.iedu?report=BS&symbol="+(Ticker)).get();
        // Elements table = doc.select("table");
        Elements columns = doc.getElementById("fundamentalsForm").children().select("table").get(0).select("tr").get(0).select("td");
        Iterator<Element> columnIterator = columns.iterator();
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        while (columnIterator.hasNext()) {
            Element column = columnIterator.next();
            Elements rows = column.select("table").get(0).select("tr");
            Iterator<Element> rowsIterator = rows.iterator();
            col = col + 1;
            while (rowsIterator.hasNext()){
                row = row + 1;
                //Element rowIterator.next = ;
                cashFlowsInfo[col][row] = rowsIterator.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateCompanyInfo(String Ticker) throws IOException {
    /** LINE 134**/ 
        updateCompanyIs();
        updateCompanyBs();
        updateCompanyCf();

    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Company.updateCompanyIs(Company.java:72)
    at Company.updateCompanyInfo(Company.java:134)
    at Company.<init>(Company.java:41)
    at AppGUI.main(AppGUI.java:124)
```

And this is my AppGUI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Company company = new Company("KO"); // Creates new Company. Updating methods are called from constructor automatically.
    AppGUI frame = new AppGUI(company); // Creates new App GUI.  Various panes are initialized from constructor.
    frame.retrieveGUI(company);
    frame.setTitle("Financial Calculator | Ratios");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I think my JSOUP code is correct, but I could have gotten confused with the select and node elements, as  well as the query.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding line 72, if this were my code, I'd break the long chained method line up and put each method call on its own line, the better to see which method call is causing the NPE. Also consider using debug statements as well.

Comment: I broke it up and it still said line 72. I have tried using a toString print out to at each intervals and they all failed.

Comment: this would lead me to believe it has to do with getElementById, but it doesn't make sense

Comment: Have you checked to see if doc is null before using it? Something like `System.out.println("doc is null: " + (doc == null));`?

Comment: Are you sure that you have authenticated to the app at investools.com?

Comment: I am not positive. I created a secure login, exported and imported the certificate. And didn't get any errors, which I know doesn't necessarily mean there is anything wrong.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
        at Company.updateCompanyIs(Company.java:70)
        at Company.updateCompanyInfo(Company.java:144)
        at Company.<init>(Company.java:41)
        at AppGUI.main(AppGUI.java:124)

Comment: '  public void investoolsLogin(){
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  
  client.getParams().setParameter("username", "asfdsafdf");  
  client.getParams().setParameter("password", "*******");  
   
  GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://online.investools.com/authentication/auth.iedu");  
  client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.single-cookie-header", true);
  client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
  }'

Comment: ^^that was my login method minues correct user and password

Comment: doc is null: false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Company.updateCompanyIs(Company.java:74)
        at Company.updateCompanyInfo(Company.java:144)
        at Company.<init>(Company.java:41)
        at AppGUI.main(AppGUI.java:124)

Answer (score 0):

Line 72:  `Elements columns = doc.getElementById("fundamentalsForm").children().select("table").get(0).select("tr").get(0).select("td");`

Judging by the comments, it appears that `doc.getElementById("fundamentalsForm")` is generating the NPE.

I would suspect that every valid page has the "fundamentalsForm" form, so that shouldn't be the issue. Did you check and see that you aren't triggering an error page (i.e. the ticker isn't registered)?

Comment: I haven't checked and I am not sure how I would. I know KO is registered. It is Coke. But I did find that the name of the username and password form was actually userid and password.

Comment: I'm thinking you are right, but I don't know how to find out to what page the program is going to.